# Read chunks of data sent in a socket without knowing what the length of data

Tags: c, sockets

I am creating WebSocket code in C and I'm trying to read parts of the socket and store each to a buffer address. For example, I have a string sent in a socket:

ABCD......

How do I read it from the socket and put each character in a buffer address

BUF[0],BUF[1],.....

I want to use `read(socket,...,...);`

I tried to do it like this:

```
read(socket, buf[0],1); // for reading first byte of the socket 
read(socket, buf+1,1); // for reading 2nd byte of the socket
....
```

but I am not sure if it is the right way.

Comment: You can `read` more bytes and check the return value to see how many it read.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below approach to read bytes from the socket.

```
// It's a good idea to read some bytes at a time
char buffer[1024]; 

// Buffer index
int index = 0;

// Bytes read by the socket in one go
ssize_t bytesRead;


while (1) // break condition specified on the basis of bytes read
{
    bytesRead = read(socket, buffer + index, sizeof(buffer) - index);   

    if ( bytesRead <= 0 )
    {
         // No more bytes to read from the socket, terminate the loop
         break;
    }

    // bytesRead has the number of bytes that have been already read,
    // Use it to increment the buffer index.
    index += bytesRead;
}
```

Comment: note that this will fail if buffer is not a compile-time allocated array (```char buffer[1024]```) but runtime malloc'ed (```char *buffer = (char *)malloc(1024*sizeof(char));```). In this case ```sizeof(buffer)``` must be replaced by the allocated memory size (e.g. 1024). Sorry if being pedantic.

Answer (score -1):

Already found the answer , once you want to read again from  the socket the offset on the socket changes to the last data you read in your last use of "read()" so the example that i posted is correct

Comment: FYI: The example you posted has an error. You're dereferencing the pointer here: `buf[0]` , but what you meant to do is `buf + 0`...